# Weird compile error regarding to C++ std::pair

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the code and error message, any thoughts why? I tried after removing this line of code `Building t = beginEndMap[b.id];`, compile is ok. But cannot figure out the casual of this line to the error. This line is not pair related, but the compile error is pair related.

**Error message**,

```
Error:
  required from 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {const int&}; _Args2 = {}; _T1 = const int; _T2 = Building]'
```

**Source code**,

```
struct Building {
    int id;
    int pos;
    int height;
    bool isStart;
    Building(int i, int p, int h, int s) {
        id = i;
        pos = p;
        height = h;
        isStart = s;
    }
};

class Solution {
public:
    vector<pair<int, int>> getSkyline(vector<vector<int>>& buildings) {
        vector<Building> sortedBuilding;
        unordered_map<int, Building> beginEndMap;
        vector<pair<int, int>> result;
        for (Building b : sortedBuilding) {
            Building t = beginEndMap[b.id];
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

Long story short, if you use `unordered_map::operator[]` then `Building` needs to be `DefaultConstructible` which it isn't. Hence the (criptic) error.

This happens because `operator[]` will do an insertion if the key is not found.

The requirements go like this:

> `value_type` (a.k.a `std::pair<const int, Building>` (my note)) must be `EmplaceConstructible` from
>
> ```
> std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(key), std::tuple<>()
> ```
>
> When the default allocator is used, this means that `key_type` (`int`
>   in your case)  must be `CopyConstructible` and **`mapped_type`
>   (`Building` in your case) must be `DefaultConstructible`**.

## The Solution

is to have a default constructor for `Building`, or use `unordered_map::at` which will throw if the key is not found and so it doesn't have this requirement.

---

> why the compile error related to pair other than something related
>   to unsorted_map?

Because `std::pair` is used internally to store the `key`-`value` pairs.

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains **key-value
>   pairs** with unique keys

and because these kind of criptic errors you get when you have templates. C++ concepts are underway, which will (hopefully) improve drastically exactly this kind of errors.

---

[std::unordered_map::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

Comment: But my `key_type` is `int` other than `Building`, see the definition `unordered_map<int, Building> beginEndMap`, and do you mean `value_type` other than `key_type`?

Comment: Thanks, your reply makes sense to me, but why the compile error related to pair other than something related to unsorted_map?

Comment: @LinMa ok, I think now I got it. Sorry for the mistakes I made, I am kind of tired. This edit now should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, mark your reply as answer. Have a relax!